# Git worktrees in VSCode devcontainer

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I would like to use VSCode devcontainers with Git worktrees. I'm following [these instructions](https://morgan.cugerone.com/blog/workarounds-to-git-worktree-using-bare-repository-and-cannot-fetch-remote-branches/) to get a directory layout where all branches I'm working on are side-by-side. It results in something like the following:

```
my-repo:
.
├── .bare
├── .git
├── main
└── feat-pytest-helpers
```

I can open the `my-repo` folder in VSCode and it will recognize the various worktrees right off the bat. Each of the branch folders has their own `.devcontainer` subfolder. However, VSCode won't offer to reopen in a devcontainer when I select a specific branch folder and I can see no way to "force" it to do so. The instructions [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/change-default-source-mount) look relevant, but I think that then I won't be able to see the different different folders (branches) in the Explorer menu anymore.

In summary:

- I would like to be able to open the `my-repo` folder with VSCode, so that I can see the subfolders and switch between them in the Explorer menu.
- Trigger a rebuild&reopen in devcontainer whenever I switch between subfolders.

Is this at all possible? If not, are you aware of any workarounds?